# Is it possible to run an asynchronous function without making the main function as async?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to run an asynchronous function without making the main function as async?

```
function index() {
    console.log('1');
    aaa();
    console.log('3');
}

async function aaa() {
    return await bbb().then((value) => {
        console.log(value);
    });
}

async function bbb() {
    return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve('2');
        }, 1000);
    });
}

index();
```

It is possible to display:

> 1

> 2

> 3

Without making the index function as async?

Comment: Could do `aaa().then(res=>console.log('3'));`.

Comment: Making `aaa` and `bbb` `async` is pointless because you only use `await` on the value you immediately return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `aaa` returns a `Promise`, you can always interact directly with that `Promise` instead of using `await`.  For example:

```
function index() {
  console.log('1');
  aaa().then(() => console.log('3'));
}
```

That way the code in the `.then()` callback won't execute until after the `Promise` returned by `aaa()` resolves.

---

For the most part, without peeking under the hood to the inner workings of JavaScript, `async` and `await` tends to just be a cleaner and simpler way of expressing this same thing.  For this simple example, there really shouldn't be a meaningful difference between this:

```
function index() {
  console.log('1');
  return aaa().then(() => console.log('3'));
}
```

And this:

```
async function index() {
  console.log('1');
  await aaa();
  console.log('3');
}
```

The main difference between these and the function at the top of this answer is that the one at the top doesn't *advertise* that it internally has asynchronous operations.  So *it* can't be awaited.  If that's not an issue for your needs, no big deal.  But even then, going with `async` and `await` still does the same thing and consuming code can simply *choose not to* await this function.

Answer (score 3):

You need to do **something** to cause `console.log('3')` to run after the promise returned by `aaa()` has been resolved.

Making `index` `async` and using `await` is the approach that most people find easiest to write and maintain.

```
async function index() {
    console.log('1');
    await aaa();
    console.log('3');
}
```

You could use `then()` instead.

```
function index() {
    console.log('1');
    aaa().then(
        () => { console.log('3'); }
    );
    
}
```

Comment: [IIAFE](https://2ality.com/2016/10/async-function-tips.html#immediately-invoked-async-function-expressions) is yet another approach.

Comment: @Wyck — I don't see how that would help here. The problem is inside a function, not in the top level of the script.

Comment: `function iamnotasync() { (async function () { console.log('1'); await aaa(); console.log('3') })(); }`  Doesn't really "help" -- just another approach.